# How to get the same value without clicking the button

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

2 textbox in the Form (textbox1.text, textbox2.text)

Once user entered the value in the textbox1 means automatically textbox1 value should appear in the textbox2 without clicking the buttons.

In which event i have to write a code instead of button clicking event....

Need vb.net code Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
  Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text

  End Sub
```

Every time you type a value in textbox1 it will appear in textbox2